# SLAM motion and measurement models

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would like to implement SLAM with the Kinect for a research project. I am not sure which motion and measurement models to apply though. Would anyone be able to recommend which models I can apply to the Kinect or a good place to start. I will be using ROS. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65507/slam-motion-and-measurement-models/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just did a similar project last semester. The motion will depend on the robot you are using. For the measurement model we extracted lines from the cloud of points and registered the robot with them.

---

Originally posted by [focs](https://answers.ros.org/users/5185/focs/) with karma: 46 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thank you, is there a link where I could look at the models you used? (I know they are probably complex to type out) Thanks

**Comment by [focs](https://answers.ros.org/users/5185/focs/) on 2013-06-19**:
This pdf has more or less all the needed parts: webdiis.unizar.es/~neira/SLAM.pdf‎

**Comment by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on 2013-06-19**:
Thank you, much appreciated. Will look through.